Bootstrap container overflow and crashing with adminlte3 jsf template
Within my java jsf project, I am using the adminlte 3 plugin with bootstrap, however in the main body of the plugin which uses the content-wrapper class, when I add bootstrap containers with its grid system, they overflow or are not placed correctly.
Here is the code of my layout.xhtml
<div class="wrapper">
    <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
       <div class="sidebar"></div>  
    </aside> 
</div>
        <div class="content-wrapper" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
            <ui:insert name="cuerpoModulo"></ui:insert>
    </div>

In the code I just provided is the base part of my project which is implemented in all views, following my client.xhtml:
<ui:composition template="../layout.xhtml">
<ui:define name="titulo">ADPIN - Sistema Administrativo Financiero - Menu Principal</ui:define>

<ui:define name="cuerpoModulo">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="border: 1px solid red; height:30px;">
        <div class="container mx-3" style="border: 1px solid green;height:15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container mx-3 my-2" style="border: 1px solid red;height:30px;">
        <div class="container mx-3" style="border: 1px solid green;height:15px;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container mr-5" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 30px;'"></div>
</ui:define>




</ui:composition>

The containers look something like this:

Why does this happen and the boostrap containers don't work like a normal page?
